# Payment Gateways: pay a percentage to two different accounts

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, stripe.js

For an e-commerce site I am building, for every transaction 90% needs to go to one account and 10% needs to go to another.

It looks as though Stripe can handle this using the 'Express' account using 'Connect', but it seems this account type is unavailable outside the US (we are based in Hong Kong).

It also looks like Paypal has 'Adaptive Payments' which would achieve the same result, but it says:

```
Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.
```

As this is a very small website I don't want to go through the hassle of being a 'select partner' and they probably won't let me anyway. Is there any other way to achieve this?

If it makes any difference I will be using Drupal for the store.

Answer (score 1):

Since adaptive payment is a limited release product, you may want to look at Braintree Marketplace. Basically, it works just like adaptive payment where you can split the payment. For availability, you will need to contact their sales team. For more information, refer this [Braintree Marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-hk/products/braintree-marketplace)